# Pressing tableFooterView calls tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath, tablefooterview

I am working on a `UITableView` with a custom row (single row), that I load from a separate `xib` file. `UITableView` also has a sticky `footer view`.

Everything is working fine except that when I tap on the `footer view`, the `UITableView's` delegate method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` is being called, and that's weird.

The `IndexPath` that I received inside that method is [0,0]. Now how that is problematic for me? Well I am doing a certain thing when the cell of that tableview is pressed. But under the current scenario, that certain thing is also being done when I press footer view instead of the cell.

The code for UITableView is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
        withIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.INVITE_CELL_ID,
        for: indexPath) as? InviteCell else {

        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    // cell configuration

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if (contacts.count > 0) {

        guard let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.INVITE_FOOTER_CELL_ID)
            as? InviteFooter else {

                return nil
        }

        footer.delegate = self

        return footer
    }
    return nil
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    if (contacts.count > 0) {
        return 90
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Can you post the footer implementation code?

Comment: Could you update the question with some code? how do you load the cell? how do you set the tableFooterView? You could use a section footer instead?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: There are other delegate and datasource methods there too, like didSelectRowAt and numberOfSections

Comment: Why are you using a cell as footerView? that is strange. Also, what does the `footer.delegate`? does it handle selection?

Comment: Maybe there is a cell hidden under your footer, triggering the selectRow method?

Comment: There's only one cell inside the tableview , and that is appearing above the footer view. So i don't think there's any cell hidden under it. And i was using two sections at first, and then i decided to use one section only and use footer view instead of second section. That's why i have a cell for footer view. Do you think this maybe a problem? and is should use view instead of cell?

Comment: @MeeranTariq - it does seem a bit odd to use a `UITableViewCell` for a section footer view, particularly if you only have one section. Tough to say what might be going on though, without more code (like, what's going on in that "footer cell"?). If you replace the section footer view with a regular view and the problem persists, review [mcve] to get more help here.

Comment: I agree with @DonMag, try returning a UIView(with nothing more) instead of a cell and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @DonMag thanks man, that actually was the issue. Using UIView solved the problem.

Comment: @Lucho thanks to you too man

Comment: @MeeranTariq Glad it helped!